# Retro-active effective date changes with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I need to assign an appropriate rate to an employees timecard. The employee will record thier time regardless of a rate (i.e. it is unavilable when recording time).  The system that stores the rates will receive daily updates and rates can be back-dated (retro-active) to any point within the costing period.  For reporting purposes, I need to be able to report the rate on specific days.  Consider the following tables:

```
create table #timesheet (
    txid int identity(1,1) 
  , empid int
  , work_date datetime
  , jobno varchar(16)
  , hoursamt decimal(8,2)
)

create table #payrate (
    txid int identity(1,1) 
  , empid int
  , rate money
  , eff_date datetime
  , asof_date datetime
)

insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 1, '2010-01-01', 'A', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 1, '2010-01-02', 'A', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 1, '2010-01-03', 'A', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 1, '2010-01-04', 'A', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 2, '2010-01-01', 'B', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 2, '2010-01-02', 'B', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 2, '2010-01-03', 'B', 8 )
insert into #timesheet ( empid, work_date, jobno, hoursamt ) values ( 2, '2010-01-04', 'B', 8 )

insert into #payrate ( empid, rate, eff_date, asof_date ) values ( 1, 10, '2010-01-01', '2010-01-01' )      -- Starting rate
insert into #payrate ( empid, rate, eff_date, asof_date ) values ( 1, 11, '2010-01-03', '2010-01-05' )      -- Retro active
insert into #payrate ( empid, rate, eff_date, asof_date ) values ( 2, 8,  '2010-01-01', '2010-01-01' )      -- Starting rate
insert into #payrate ( empid, rate, eff_date, asof_date ) values ( 2, 9,  '2010-01-03', '2010-01-02' )      -- Retro active date
insert into #payrate ( empid, rate, eff_date, asof_date ) values ( 2, 10, '2010-01-01', '2010-01-05' )      -- Retro active date
```

I would like a query that accepts one parameter (the asof_date) which indicates the date the rates were effective.  The same query would return the following results given the following 'asof' dates.  Note that retro-active changes take effect on the 'asof' date in the payrate table.  Assume that rates are effective until changed via an entry in the payrate table.  Cost = rate * hoursamt.  Dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format.  The notes are for reference only and should not be returned in the result set.

```
declare @asof datetime
set @asof = '2010-01-01'

----------------------------------------------------
empid | work_date | jobno | hoursamt | rate | cost | Notes
----------------------------------------------------
1       2010-01-01  A       8          10     80     Rate effective the 1st  
1       2010-01-02  A       8          10     80
1       2010-01-03  A       8          10     80
1       2010-01-04  A       8          10     80
2       2010-01-01  B       8          8      64     Rate effective the 1st  
2       2010-01-02  B       8          8      64
2       2010-01-03  B       8          8      64
2       2010-01-04  B       8          8      64



declare @asof datetime
set @asof = '2010-01-03'

----------------------------------------------------
empid | work_date | jobno | hoursamt | rate | cost | Notes
----------------------------------------------------
1       2010-01-01  A       8          10     80     Rate effective the 1st  
1       2010-01-02  A       8          10     80
1       2010-01-03  A       8          10     80
1       2010-01-04  A       8          10     80
2       2010-01-01  B       8          8      64       
2       2010-01-02  B       8          8      64
2       2010-01-03  B       8          9      72     Rate effective the 3rd
2       2010-01-04  B       8          9      72


declare @asof datetime
set @asof = '2010-01-06'

----------------------------------------------------
empid | work_date | jobno | hoursamt | rate | cost | Notes
----------------------------------------------------
1       2010-01-01  A       8          10     80       
1       2010-01-02  A       8          10     80
1       2010-01-03  A       8          11     88     Rate effective the 3rd
1       2010-01-04  A       8          11     88
2       2010-01-01  B       8          10     80     Rate effective the 1st
2       2010-01-02  B       8          10     80
2       2010-01-03  B       8          10     80
2       2010-01-04  B       8          10     80
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: declare @maxdate datetime, @asof datetime 
set @asof = '2010-01-06' 
set @maxdate = '2199-01-01'
select t.empid, t.work_date, t.jobno, t.hoursamt, r.rate, t.hoursamt * r.rate as cost
from #timesheet t
  inner join (
 select empid
  , rate
  , eff_date as eff_from
  , ( select isnull(min(b.eff_date), @maxdate) as eff_from
     from #payrate b
     where b.empid = a.empid
       and b.eff_date > a.eff_date
    and b.asof_date < @asof
    ) as eff_thru
 from #payrate a
 where asof_date <= @asof
  ) as r on t.empid = r.empid and (t.work_date between r.eff_from and r.eff_thru)

Comment: I used the above code but it is returning duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `outer apply` to search for a specific payrate.  This example combines an `outer apply` with a `top 1` to select the most recent payrate.

```
select  t.empid
,       t.work_date
,       t.jobno
,       t.hoursamt
,       rate.rate
,       t.hoursamt * rate.rate
from    #timesheet t
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    #payrate p
        where   p.empid = t.empid
                and p.asof_date <= @asof
                and p.eff_date <= t.work_date
        order by
                p.eff_date desc
        ) rate
```