# SQL query that selects effective costing rate based on charge date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL novice here. I'm trying to generate a costing query that outputs employee time card information and calculates cost based on an effective employee costing rate.

My question is similar to the one asked here: [Retro-active effective date changes with overlapping dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541993/retro-active-effective-date-changes-with-overlapping-dates) but I'm not dealing with retro-activity or overlapping date ranges.

Table examples (null values in the rate table indicate current rate):

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_Rate
(
    Emp int,
    Rate money,
    Rate_Start datetime,
    Rate_Exp datetime
)

CREATE TABLE Emp_Time
(
    Emp int,
    Chrg_Date datetime,
    Chrg_Code varchar(10),
    Chrg_Hrs decimal(8, 2)
)

Insert into Emp_Rate (Emp,Rate,Rate_Start,Rate_Exp) Values ('1','20','5/1/09','4/30/10')
Insert into Emp_Rate (Emp,Rate,Rate_Start,Rate_Exp) Values ('1','21','5/1/10','4/30/11')
Insert into Emp_Rate (Emp,Rate,Rate_Start,Rate_Exp) Values ('1','22','5/1/11',NULL)

Insert into Emp_Time (Emp,Chrg_Date,Chrg_Code,Chrg_Hrs) Values ('1','5/10/09','B','8')
Insert into Emp_Time (Emp,Chrg_Date,Chrg_Code,Chrg_Hrs) Values ('1','5/10/10','B','8')
Insert into Emp_Time (Emp,Chrg_Date,Chrg_Code,Chrg_Hrs) Values ('1','5/10/11','B','8')
```

The query (returns dupes caused by multiple rate entries(obviously)):

```
Select  Emp_Time.Emp,
        Cast(Emp_Time.Chrg_Date as DATE) as 'Chrg_Date',
        Emp_Time.Chrg_Code,
        Emp_Time.Chrg_Hrs,
        Emp_Rate.Rate,
        Emp_Time.Chrg_Hrs * Emp_Rate.Rate as 'Cost'

From    Emp_Time inner join
        Emp_Rate on Emp_Rate.Emp = Emp_Time.Emp

Order By [Emp],[Chrg_Date]
```

Desired output:

```
Emp Chrg_Date   Chrg_Code   Chrg_Hrs    Rate    Cost
1   2009-05-10  B           8.00        20.00   160.00
1   2010-05-10  B           8.00        21.00   168.00
1   2011-05-10  B           8.00        22.00   176.00
```

I've gone around in circles using the `Between` operator in a sub query to isolate the correct rate based on the charge date, but have not had any luck.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: +1 for the detailed question.  Your desired output is showing Emp 2 but your inserts are for Emp 1. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes it was typo! My original example had two employees. Corrected.

Comment: Tag your question with your database type. MySQL?

Comment: Databse type is SQL Server (first post learning curve)

Comment: +1 For DDL and INSERT queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the DBMS type the answer below is for sql-server. I am sure there are other ways to do this but this way will replace the `null` `Rate_Exp` date with the current date.

```
Select  et.Emp,
        Cast(et.Chrg_Date as DATEtime) as 'Chrg_Date',
        et.Chrg_Code,
        et.Chrg_Hrs,
        er.Rate,
        et.Chrg_Hrs * er.Rate as 'Cost'
From  Emp_Time et
inner join 
(
    SELECT Emp
        , Rate
        , Rate_Start
        , CASE
            WHEN Rate_Exp is Null
            THEN Convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
            ELSE Rate_Exp
          END as Rate_Exp
    FROM Emp_Rate 
)er 
    on er.Emp = et.Emp
WHERE (et.Chrg_Date BETWEEN er.Rate_Start AND er.Rate_Exp)
Order By et.Emp,et.Chrg_Date
```

OR use the `CASE` Statement in your `WHERE` Clause:

```
Select  et.Emp,
        Cast(et.Chrg_Date as DATEtime) as 'Chrg_Date',
        et.Chrg_Code,
        et.Chrg_Hrs,
        er.Rate,
        et.Chrg_Hrs * er.Rate as 'Cost'
From  Emp_Time et
inner join Emp_Rate er
    on er.Emp = et.Emp
WHERE (et.Chrg_Date 
        BETWEEN er.Rate_Start 
                AND CASE WHEN er.Rate_Exp Is Null 
            THEN  Convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
            ELSE er.Rate_Exp END)
```

Comment: This looks great! I have to patch it into a query with a bunch more joins which should be fun. Thanks for giving me a couple options!

Comment: Implemented and works like a charm. Elected to use the second solution for its elegance.